# Rails Json response automatically changes timezeone only on some requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, jbuilder

We have a simple json API in rails 4 that returns the data using jbuilder. One of the fields is a datetime field "date_of_birth" the json formatting is acting strangely. The same request to the API can randomly generate 2 different results

```
"date_of_birth":"1989-06-14T20:52:00-07:00"

"date_of_birth":"1989-06-15T03:52:00Z"
```

As you can see the first one is in local time as the other one is in UTC timezone. We have the  timezone globally set to "UTC".

this is the line in the jbuilder view that produces the output, nothing special'

```
json.array!(@patients) do |patient|
  json.extract! patient, :id, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :groups_code, :date_of_birth
end
```

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the config of  `config.time_zone` in your development.rb ?

Comment: I have config.time_zone = 'UTC' in my config/application.rb. This is happening in all environments.

Comment: I have this problem as well. I can fire off the same API call over and over again and it comes back with the different format with no rhyme or reason.

Answer (score 2):

Rails is doing some pretty clever work with times in order to cover users with different time-zones and server independent hosting location. Basically times are stored in the database in UTC zone, and converted when needed to the local server/or user time zone.

In a standard Rails app you have 3 times zones that can be the same or can be different: Database time zone, default time zone, and user time zone.

Have a look at this very good [article](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails) that says it all. Then apply the right method to your `date_of_birth` field while exporting to json

DOs

```
2.hours.ago # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 20:04:47 JST +09:00
1.day.from_now # => Fri, 03 Mar 2012 22:04:47 JST +09:00
Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 22:04:47 JST +09:00
Date.current # => Fri, 02 Mar
Time.zone.parse("2012-03-02 16:05:37") # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 16:05:37 JST +09:00
Time.zone.now # => Fri, 02 Mar 2012 22:04:47 JST +09:00
Time.current # Same thing but shorter. (Thank you Lukas Sarnacki pointing this out.)
Time.zone.today # If you really can't have a Time or DateTime for some reason
Time.zone.now.utc.iso8601 # When supliyng an API (you can actually skip .zone here, but I find it better to always use it, than miss it when it's needed)
Time.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').in_time_zone(Time.zone) # If you can't use Time#parse
```

DON'Ts

```
Time.now # => Returns system time and ignores your configured time zone.
Time.parse("2012-03-02 16:05:37") # => Will assume time string given is in the system's time zone.
Time.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') # Same problem as with Time#parse.
Date.today # This could be yesterday or tomorrow depending on the machine's time zone.
Date.today.to_time # => # Still not the configured time zone.
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to the article, very helpful. But I am still confused as why would rails return 2 different responses for 2 requests coming from the same client.

Comment: same issue here!

Answer (score 2):

You may have `Time.zone = ...` set somewhere based on user time zone setting.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this same problem and have not been able to figure out why it happens. The other answers here seem to be missing the point that which  time format is returned is seemingly random, with no changes to code/config whatsoever.

I was able to "fix" this issue by using `.to_time.iso8601` my JBuilder block which will force the `1989-06-15T03:52:00Z` format.